# Listview is not getting updated immediately after button click

Tags: android

I have a list view that contains Product (productid, productname) + one button

I am filling ArrayList below.

```
ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
//fill products here
productAdapter adapter = new ProductAdapter(getApplicationContext(), products);
productListView.setAdapter(adapter);
productListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Now in adapter

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

// some other code

    holder.btn_addtocart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        products.get(position).setname("ABC");

       }
    });
}
```

Problem is its not updating immediately. When we scroll down and up its getting changed.

Why is not not updating listview immediately?

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the list, you need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after updating the data.

eg:

```
holder.btn_addtocart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          products.get(position).setname("ABC");
          notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for very quick response. Now i have 2 answers. so my question is which is more optimized and better way? notifyItemChanged(position); or notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: You're welcome..., `notifyItemChanged` is  more optimized if you have a  `RecyclerView`, but in your case you use a `ListView` so you only have `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.